# Cassandra Error : errors={}, last_host=127.0.0.1

Tags: cassandra

Cassandra version = 2.1.2

I created 3 vnodes using CCM tool and try to connect to specific nodes using cqlsh. Working fine.When I try to create a table in node1(same issue with node2 & node3 as well) I'm facing this error :

> errors={}, last_host=127.0.0.1

```
Connected to cascor at 127.0.0.1:9042.
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.1.2-SNAPSHOT | CQL spec 3.2.0 | Native protocol v3]
Use HELP for help.
cqlsh> use musicdb;
cqlsh:musicdb> CREATE TABLE user (
           ... id UUID,
           ... name VARCHAR,
           ... PRIMARY KEY (id)
           ... );
```

**errors={}, last_host=127.0.0.1**

Thanks
Venkat

Comment: That doesn't seem like an error. Was the table created? can you check "describe tables" ?

Comment: Hi Sreekar - No, table not created.